# @font-face: checking font version?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Embedding fonts with @font-face, is there a way to check for particular version of an installed font on client side?

Let me explain. If I want browser to use local font if present, I write something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  src: local('Calibri'), url('some_path/calibri.ttf');
}
```

But now I want to use some OpenType features that Calibri supports only starting with version 5.72 (Windows 8). With the preceding declaration, browsers in Windows 7 (or earlier) will use local Calibri font without these features. And if I remove ‘local’:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  src: url('some_path/calibri.ttf');
}
```

— then all browsers will download the font file, even if it is already installed in the OS.

Is there a way to make browser to download a font only if there is no local font with the same name and with the right version? E.g., if there is local Calibri font version 5.72 (or newer), then use it, otherwise download font file.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. The `@font-face` rule doesn't has "version descriptor" or "features descriptor", as you can see in the [current Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-fonts-3-20131003/#font-face-rule).